# Repeat an animation 2 or 3 times before easing it out

Tags: css, animation

How can I repeat a spinning animation x times before easing it out ?

For instance :

```css
#spin-please {
 background: green;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 animation: spin 3s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  49% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="spin-please">
</div>
```

My animation right now is not very smooth at all (as you can see between the 1st and 2nd rotation), and there is an easing between the 2 rotations, which I want only at the start of the first of the rotation and at the end of the second (or the third if I choose to go with an additional rotation).

> Easing in ==> rotation 1 ==> rotation 2 ==> easing out

Is this doable with CSS ?

Comment: what exactly is easing in and out? the rotations?

Comment: edit : I thought you were asking what easing meant. Yes the rotations.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of repeating the animation infinite times, you can specify a number of repetitions like this:

```
animation: spin 3s 3 ease-in-out; /* 3secs, repeat 3 times */
```

See [animation iteration count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) for more examples.

Also useful to see the `animation` [short-hand docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) to set all the properties at once (like your code does)

I am not sure what the desired outcome you are looking for but I modified the animation to display the spinning happening three times (with some reversal spin as well)

```css
#spin-please {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /* @keyframes duration | timing-function | delay | 
      iteration-count | direction | fill-mode | play-state | name 
    */
  animation: 1s 3 spin;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in, linear, ease-out;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="spin-please">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually already tried doing it this way, but css doesn't allow me to set the easing only at begging at the first rotation and the end of the thrid rotation. Doing it this way puts an easing between every rotation.   What I'm trying to do is easing-in -> 2-3 rotations -> easing out

Comment: @eloism I am afraid this is the best I can do... not sure it's what you are seeking though.

Comment: Indeed ! your comment is actually the whole solution to my problem, thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is totally not because your `animation` isn't smooth,
the problem with `keyframes`, according to this code

```
49% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
```

Your animation have to do `360deg` rotation in very short time which is 1% ( between `49%` - `50%`) for any `animation-timing-function` value your animation is not smooth, Try this code :

```css
#spin-please {
 background: green;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 animation: spin 3s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
```

```html
<div id="spin-please">
</div>
```

Remember you can change your `animation-timing-function` in your keyframes. more details about [animation-timing-function](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/animation-timing-function/).

Comment: Yes it looks indeed better that way. However the reason for my weird 49-50% is that I was trying to set a ns rotation in the ame animation. 50% is 360deg, and 100% would have been 720deg

Comment: @eloism try  `transform: rotate(720deg);` , And for your question just add `animation-timing-function` in your keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#spin-it {
    background: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    animation: spin 1.5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
25% {transform: rotate(90deg);}
50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
75% {transform: rotate(270deg);}
100% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
```

```html
<div id="spin-it">
</div>
```

My version of MMJ's
It goes through 5 steps.
Ease in >>> Turn 1 side >>> Turn 1 side >>> Turn 1 side >>> Turn 1 side >>> Ease out